# How to store null value in hdf5 table?

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables, h5py

I want to store null value in hdf5 file.

```
h5file = tables.open_file("demo.h5", mode="w", title="demo")
group  = h5file.create_group('/', 'depth','Dept Data information')
table = h5file.create_table(group, 'readout', depthdata , "depth data")
row_data = table.row
for i in range(len(record['local_timestamp'])):
        if record['bbno1'][i] is '':
            row_data['bbno1']  = NaN 
        else:
            row_data['bbno1'] = record['bbno1'][i]
```

I used these code but its not work. I used NaN and NULL but its not work.

Answer (score 4):

HDF5 doesn't have a NULL in its type model (it's not a relational database). Generally, if a dataset has been extended but not written to, you will get the fill value, which has a default value of zero, however that is interpreted for a particular HDF5 type.

If you want to store a value with 'bad' or 'non-existing' semantics in your HDF5 data, you will have to come up with your own special value and check for that yourself. Alternatively, if you are unable to determine a special value, you could create an extra dataset (or field in a compound type) that indicated whether the data value was valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay storing the hdf5 table using the 'table' format, then you can store a numpy nan using pandas' `to_hdf` method (which uses pytables):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'foo': np.nan}])
df.to_hdf('out.h5', key='bar', format='table', index=False, data_columns=df.columns.to_list())
```

The datatype has to be a float though.